# What are some good choices for doing diffs between text documents?

Tags: webapp-rec, offline

I often have large chunks of text (like code or some data) that I want to do a diff on but am too lazy to create two new files, run `diff` on them both, and then scan the output.

Are there any good web apps that show you diffs?

What about ones specifically for code?

Or ones that do it completely in-browser to respect your privacy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quick Diff Online Tool](http://www.quickdiff.com/)

Comment: Gives time outs for larger files

Answer (score 0):

I made my own utility for this purpose, [JavaScript Client Side Diff Tool](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/12/javascript-client-side-diff-tool.html) which uses jsdifflib.

The main advantage is that it's all JavaScript client code so none of your data is sent across the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Best online tool I know of: http://www.diffchecker.com/
But I prefer using offline tools as online tools get slow with very large pieces of text.